# How many pages can be printed continuously on HP LaserJet 1020 - 1020 Plus Single Function Laser Printer at 40 degree celsius

Tags: printing, printer, hp-laserjet

I am using HP LaserJet 1020 - 1020 Plus Single Function Laser Printer for printing books. When I give the command to print multiple pages two or three times the printer eventually stops printing. For example at first I printed 10 pages continuously it went ok but when I again gave a command to print 10 pages more, the printer printed only 3 pages and stopped. The problem becomes worse when I try to duplex. I have to calculate the number of page and then I have to print each single page separately. Even when I print pages one by one the printer stops. If I give the command to print the next page--nothing happens. The command rests in the queue, I cancel the command, give the same command again, it still doesn't print, I give the command third time and then it prints some pages and the problem starts again.

What I suspect is that there is some heating problem. The temperature, nowadays is around 40 degrees. Once my printer stopped; I blew air behind the printer it eventually started to print again. But the trick works rarely.

The printer is new and still in guarantee. There doesn't seem to be any connectivity problem.

So,

> - Am I printing too many pages continuously? If yes then what is the threshold for HP LaserJet 1020?
> - Is this because of excessive heating? The temperature down here is 35-40.
> - Do I need to clean the printer from inside or something?

Any helps will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If the printer is still under warranty, contact HP.  They will either answer your question or fix/replace the printer.

Comment: Have you tried putting a fan directly on the printer to see if the air flows better thus keeping the printer within an operating temperature range?

Comment: @sunk818 I'll try this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [HP LaserJet 1020 specifications](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00312638&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en#N631), your ambient temperature is too high for the printer to operate effectively. I do not know for sure, but it is likely a safety feature to prevent the printer from overheating and damaging itself.

Operating Temperature is 10°C to 32.5°C (50°F to 90.5° F)
Storage Temperature is 0°C to 40°C (32°F to 104°F)

[image: Operating Conditions]

**Some options:**

- If printer is in a cramped location, move it to a location where the printer can "breathe"
- Wait until midnight to print when the temperature is cooler
- Place a fan on the printer to cool it down
- Run air conditioning in the room